# Acumatica Mobile: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: acumatica

I'm getting this cast error after adding AR301000 to the mobile app.  Version 19.103.0030 of Acumatica.  I'm getting this after clicking on a Invoice on the list screen to get into the details screen.  One of the Invoices works fine but, the rest are getting the cast error.  How can I debug this?

Here's the code that I added:

```
 add screen AR301000 {
 add container "InvoiceSummary"{
#add field "Type"
#add field "ReferenceNbr"
#add field "Status"
#add field "Date"
#add field "Customer"
#add field "Location"
#add field "CustomerOrder"
add field "Description"
#add field "SalesApproval"
#add field "FinalApproval"
#add field "DetailTotal"

add recordAction "Save" {
  behavior = Save
}

add recordAction "Cancel" {
  behavior = Cancel
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working without any issue on my system.
You can debug the code as you debug any other customization's code.
[image]
Also, you can check the Stack Trace and SQL Requests in the Request Profiler page.
Go to Request Profiler (SM205070), check all the check-boxes "Log ..." and click Refresh Results. 
[image]